# Display attribute HI and Color option WHT in display files

Tags: file, attributes, ibm-midrange

> If we select `DSPATR(HI)`,our label gets highlighted and if we select
>   `COLOR(WHT)`,label again highlights. In both case Label looks
>   highlighted i.e. `WHITE`. Then what is the difference between both
>   properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.  DSPATR(HI) was implemented before colour displays came out.  When IBM started selling colour displays, they re-used the attribute bytes.  This way, you could design a display panel and it would work on colour and monochrome displays without changes.  The [DSM manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/dsm1f.htm) has details of the 5250 data stream if you're interested.

Comment: The fact that "DSM" refers to the *Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders* in the mental health community is *probably* just a coincidence. ;)

Comment: Sorry, jargon.  DSM here means Dynamic Screen Manager :-)

Comment: According to the DDS for Display Files manual, DSPATR(HI) will be white only if no other display attributes are active.  If you have DSPATR(HI) and DSPATR(CS), then it's yellow.  If you have DSPATR(HI), DSPATR(CS), and DSPATR(BL), then it's blue. If you specify any COLOR() with DSPATR(HI), then DSPATR(HI) is ignored.